# Maximum call stack size exceeded in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

This is my self made React paginator code:

```
import React from 'react';

var Paginator = React.createClass({
componentWillReceiveProps: function (nextProps, nextState) {
    this.setState({
        pages: this.getPagesArray(nextProps),
    });

},
getDefaultProps: function () {
    return {
        perPage: '',
        getItems: '',
    }
},
getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        pages: [],
        currentPage: 1,
    }
},
getPagesArray: function (props) {
    var pages = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < props.items.length / props.perPage; i++) {
        pages.push(i + 1)
    }

    return pages;
},
getItemsForPage: function (page) {
    var first = this.props.perPage * (page - 1);
    var last = this.props.perPage * page;

    return this.props.items.slice(first, last);
},
updateItemsToShow: function (page = 1) {
    this.setState({
        currentPage: page,
    });
    var items = this.getItemsForPage(page);

    this.props.getItems(items);

    return items;
},
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            { this.props.items.length > this.props.perPage ?
                <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
                    <ul className="pagination">
                        <li>
                            <a
                                onClick={this.updateItemsToShow.bind(null, 1)} href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        {this.state.pages.map(function (page) {
                            return <li
                                className={this.state.currentPage == page ? 'active' : ''} key={page}><a
                                onClick={this.updateItemsToShow.bind(null, page)}>{page}</a>
                            </li>
                        }, this)}
                        <li>
                            <a onClick={this.updateItemsToShow.bind(null, this.state.pages[this.state.pages.length - 1])}
                               aria-label="Next">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                : null
            }
        </div>
    );
}
});

export default Paginator;
```

My problem is that I cannot call the `this.updateItemsToShow` at start. I am always receiving `Maximum call stack size exceeded.` 
I have tried all the lifecycle methods like: componentDidMount,componentWillUpdate,etc...  I am also passing the items to the parent component to display them. If I click on my buttons the `onClick` is successfully calling the method. The problem displaying the first page after the html page is fully loaded. As of now only the buttons are displayed.

The `Paginator` class is only displaying the buttons and calculating the items to send back to the parent component.

**Edit**

I am adding my parent item with my not realy elegant solution:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import  Tasks from './Tasks.js';
import  TaskControl from './task-control.js';
import  EditTask from './task-edit.js';
import  Paginator from '../Paginator.js';


var TasksShow = React.createClass({
componentDidMount: function () {
    $.get('/ajax/getStudioTasks', function (result) {
        this.setState({
            studioTasks: JSON.parse(result),
            studioTasksToShow: JSON.parse(result).slice(0, this.props.perPage),
        });
    }.bind(this));
    $.get('/ajax/getUserTasks', function (result) {
        this.setState({
            userTasks: JSON.parse(result),
            userTasksToShow: JSON.parse(result).slice(0, this.props.perPage)
        })
        ;
    }.bind(this));
},


getDefaultProps: function () {
    return {
        perPage: 10,
    }
},


getInitialState: function () {

    return {
        task: {
            id: '',
            title: '',
            description: '',
            deadline: '',
            from: {name: '', id: ''},
            to: {name: '', id: ''},
            studio: {name: '', id: ''},
            finished: '',
            finishDate: '',
            expired: '',
            almostExpired: '',
        },
        showTask: false,
        editTask: false,
        userTasks: [],
        userTasksToShow: [],
        studioTasks: [],
        studioTasksToShow: [],
    }
},
showTask: function (task) {
    this.setState({
        showTask: true,
        editTask: false,
        task: task
    });

},
hide: function () {
    this.setState({
        showTask: false,
        editTask: false
    });
},
editTask: function (task) {
    this.setState({
        showTask: false,
        editTask: true,
    });
},
updateStudioTasks: function (tasks) {
    this.setState({
        studioTasksToShow: tasks
    });

},
updateUserTasks: function (tasks) {
    this.setState({
        userTasksToShow: tasks
    });
},
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.showTask ?
                <TaskControl edit={this.editTask} hide={this.hide} task={this.state.task}/>
                : null}
            {this.state.editTask ?
                <EditTask hide={this.hide} task={this.state.task}/>
                : null}
            <div className="row margin-top">
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <Tasks tasks={this.state.studioTasksToShow} title='Studio aufgabe' onClick={this.showTask}/>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <Tasks tasks={this.state.userTasksToShow}     title='Benutzer aufgabe' onClick={this.showTask}/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6 text-center">
                        <Paginator perPage={this.props.perPage} items={this.state.studioTasks}
                                   getItems={this.updateStudioTasks}/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="col-md-6 text-center">
                        <Paginator perPage={this.props.perPage} items=         {this.state.userTasks}
                                   getItems={this.updateUserTasks}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
 });


 ReactDOM.render(
<TasksShow />
,
document.getElementById('tasks-show')
 );
```

Comment: Well maximum stack exceeded means that the array you're trying to iterate is too large, how much big is it?

Comment: Could you please share the code for this.props.getItems, which I'm assuming is getting passed by the parent component. My guess is that getItems is setting parent component state, causing Paginator to rerender, causing it to call updateItemsForPage again, which calls getItems again, etc.

Comment: Well it is not bigger than 20.